# LiveData does not infer the type to desired return value

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, mvvm, android-livedata

I have made a call to `emit()` in my viewModel, but I dont know why my `LiveDataScope` returns a `Resource<Any>` when I have defined that the `Resource` is of type `Artist`

### ViewModel

```
class EventsViewModel(private val useCase: Events):ViewModel() {

    val fetchArtistList = liveData(Dispatchers.IO){

        try {
            val artistList = useCase.getEvents()
            emit(artistList)

        }catch (e:Exception){
            Crashlytics.logException(e.cause)
            emit(Resource.error("Error: ",e.message))
        }

    }
}
```

### UseCase

```
class EventsImpl(private val eventsRepo:EventsRepo): Events {

    override suspend fun getEvents(): Resource<MutableList<Artist>> = eventsRepo.getEventsDB()
}
```

### Repo

```
class EventsRepoImpl : EventsRepo {

    override suspend fun getEventsDB(): Resource<MutableList<Artist>> {
        val artistList = mutableListOf<Artist>()
        val resultList = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
            .collection("events")
            .get().await()

        for (document in resultList) {
            val photoUrl = document.getString("photoUrl")
            val artistName = document.getString("artistName")
            val place = document.getString("place")
            val time = document.getString("time")
            val day = document.getLong("day")
            artistList.add(Artist(photoUrl!!, artistName!!, time!!, place!!, day!!))
        }

        return Resource.success(artistList)
    }
}
```

But for some reason, instead of inferring the type with `Resource<MutableList<Artist>>` in my viewmodel, it provides a `Resource<Any>` to the LiveData:

[image]

I have implemented the same way in another class but livedata is returning fine, I tried clear cache and restart, clean and rebuild but it keeps returning the same

Why is not inferring the type correctly ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is inferring correctly.  Your code is suggesting to Kotlin that the LiveData can yield two different types of objects.  You have this:

```
emit(artistList)
```

and this:

```
emit(Resource.error("Error: ",e.message))
```

The most specific common type the Kotlin can infer from that is `Resource<Any>`, since they are both Resource objects, but with different generic types.

Consider instead emitting a sealed class with two subclasses, one for the data type, and another for the error type.

Comment: can you help me a little bit with the sealed class doug ? thanks

Comment: There is a lot of documentation out there.  I suggest studying that, then ask a new question if you're having a specific problem with it.

Answer (score 0):

You can change your `Resource` implementation to this as Doug is pointing out

```
sealed class Resource<out T> {
    class Loading<out T> : Resource<T>()
    data class Success<out T>(val data: T) : Resource<T>()
    data class Failure<out T>(val throwable: Throwable) : Resource<T>()
}
```